# Disabling Multiple Textboxes VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I am trying to loop through the controls on my page and disable all of the textboxes. I found solutions that recommend doing it this way

```
For Each ctrl As Control in Me.Controls
 If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
  ctrl.Enabled = False
 End If
Next
```

However, when i attempt to do this, Enabled is not available to modify because ctrl is not of type TextBox. I then tried converting it via CType, but it did not affect any of the textboxes on the page. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: _For Each ctrl in Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)_

Comment: I tried your method, Steve, and still got the same results as before. I even tried adapting as the following
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
         ctrl.Enabled = False
    Next

Comment: But now the Enabled property is available, right? If yes then are you sure to have runat=server in your markup code? Did you set that property to true somewhere else?

Comment: No I am not getting the Enabled property.
I do have runat='server' to be true within my markup

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 For Each ctrl As WebControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

(you may be missing its declaration)

Comment: Still ending in the same result where I can not get 'z' to be a textbox/enabled is unavailable

Comment: could you provide your  VB code? and where are you trying to declare the code that i provided?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not, but I can provide a general description of what is happening:

I have a webform and in the load function, I am implementing the above methods

I have tried putting everything in a panel and then disabling that, and it works of course, but I do want to disable specific controls. Thanks, Ivan

Comment: ill be trying to imitate that in a test project.

Comment: Replace "ctrl.Enabled" by "DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox).Enabled"